# How can I use the Homebrew Python version with Homebrew MacVim on Snow Leopard?

Tags: vim, python, macvim, homebrew

> **Note:** For Mountain Lion, see: [How can I use the Homebrew Python with Homebrew MacVim on Mountain Lion?](https://superuser.com/questions/461845/how-can-i-use-the-homebrew-python-with-homebrew-macvim-on-mountain-lion?lq=1)

I've installed Python 2.7 with Homebrew on Mac OS X Snow Leopard. When I install MacVim using `brew install macvim`, it compiles with Python support, but is compiled against the system's Python installation. This can be seen by running the command:

```
:python print(sys.version)

2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jun 24 2010, 21:47:49) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)]
```

However, Vim seems to be using the Python executable that's in my path:

```
:python print(sys.executable)

/usr/local/bin/python
```

This causes problems for Vim scripts using [vim_bridge](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/vim_bridge), such as [vim-rst-tables](https://github.com/nvie/vim-rst-tables) (can't import module "re").

How can I compile Vim against my Homebrewed Python version?

Comment: Seems to be fixed now: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/26496

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, remove MacVim if you've already installed it: `brew remove macvim`

Next, edit MacVim's Formula with the command: `brew edit macvim`.  Find the arguments list (begins with `args = %W[ ...`), and modify this line:

```
--enable-pythoninterp
```

Change it to these two lines:

```
--enable-pythoninterp=dynamic
--with-python-config-dir=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/config
```

(this config dir should be symlinked to `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python2.7/config`)

Now when you reinstall MacVim with `brew install macvim`, it will use your Python 2.7 installation.

```
:python print(sys.version)

2.7.3 (default, Apr 16 2012, 23:20:02) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.1.00)]
```